# Android App Freezes on running from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello when i run the app from android studio it just freezes on the first screen and i cannot make any interaction altough i tried this with other projects which are smaller than this one and they seem to be running perfectly fine. I am posting my logcat below , any help would be highly appreciated.

Error Logcat:

```
  09-06 15:31:27.721 1346-1346/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-06 15:31:27.758 1346-1372/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-06 15:31:28.058 1397-1397/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
09-06 15:31:28.058 1397-1397/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
09-06 15:31:28.085 1397-1436/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-06 15:31:28.884 1485-1485/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
09-06 15:31:28.884 1485-1485/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
09-06 15:31:28.908 1485-1503/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-06 15:31:29.190 1397-1504/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
09-06 15:31:29.364 1397-1519/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
09-06 15:31:30.272 1579-1579/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-06 15:31:30.273 1579-1579/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-06 15:31:30.354 1581-1581/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
09-06 15:31:30.354 1581-1581/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
09-06 15:31:30.371 1581-1596/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-06 15:31:31.613 1680-1680/? E/MSimContext: MSimContext: Invalid subId in getSimContext(0). Returning the original Context
09-06 15:31:31.741 1680-1714/? E/MSimContext: MSimContext: Invalid subId in getSimContext(0). Returning the original Context
09-06 15:31:32.213 5194-7137/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=1752, uid=10092 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
                                                    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-06 15:31:34.442 1866-1866/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:34.443 1866-1866/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:34.444 1866-1866/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:34.964 1931-1931/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-06 15:31:35.066 2026-2026/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
09-06 15:31:35.066 2026-2026/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
09-06 15:31:35.092 1931-1991/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-06 15:31:35.093 2026-2070/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-06 15:31:35.265 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:35.294 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:35.353 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:35.441 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:35.562 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
09-06 15:31:35.667 2148-2148/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
09-06 15:31:35.667 2148-2148/? E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
09-06 15:31:35.706 2148-2169/? E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-06 15:31:35.808 2176-2176/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-06 15:31:35.808 2176-2176/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-06 15:31:35.924 2026-2168/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
09-06 15:31:36.086 2026-2181/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
09-06 15:31:36.373 281-2028/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
09-06 15:31:37.799 2242-2264/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mmsconfig
09-06 15:31:37.802 2242-2264/? E/Babel_SMS: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
09-06 15:31:40.831 2312-2312/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-06 15:31:40.832 2312-2312/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-06 15:31:45.218 6490-6490/? E/getNetworkTypeName: 13
09-06 15:31:45.220 6490-6490/? E/getSubNetworkTypeHidden: 13
09-06 15:31:45.858 2333-2333/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-06 15:31:45.859 2333-2333/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-06 15:31:47.660 283-846/? E/QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 0, result = 0
09-06 15:31:47.661 326-537/? E/QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
09-06 15:31:36.373 281-2028/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
09-06 15:31:36.373 281-2028/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

Comment: `SecurityException` check run time permission, https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: which line have your project package name? Something like `com.android.myapplication`. I ask because most of your logcat don't relate to your app.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel i tried on api level 21 i.e 5.0.0 and api level 19 i.e 4.4.4 still freezes.

Comment: @MehranZamani  only this line 09-06 15:31:35.265 1866-1866/media.aer.influencer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. but this cannot be the reason for the whole app to just freeze without any interaction can it ?

Comment: yes, it can. you should set an adapter to show you things and also to update them.

Comment: i have set the adapter everywhere as it is a pretty big project , funny as it was working perfectly till a couple of hours ago , i made absolutely no changes.

Comment: This problem is still not solved never experienced something like this before

Comment: also i am getting a lot of NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found

Comment: 09-07 15:06:25.138 10536-10536/? E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat, you are not supposed to set adapter everywhere, you just set it once and anywhere data change, you just call notifydatasetcganged.